# SoundCloud Cocoa Auth Popup Modal is in Portrait while UIViewController is landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, soundcloud

I'm working on integrating SoundCloud in my iOS 5 app but when I call `[scAPI checkAuthentication]` the popup modal appears in portrait mode, while my UIViewController is in landscape. This is extremely odd since for that same UIViewController I have a modal for mail compositions that appears correctly; as well, a transition to another UIViewController that appears correctly.

I'm unsure what to do, I've been looking around the web and (SoundCloud) source code to find a solution, but no luck so far.

**Update:**
This is using the [Cocoa API Wrapper from SoundCloud](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

I created my own hack-ish solution. In the SoundCloudAPI directory under Sources, in the file SCLoginViewController.m, I added the following method to the file:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation);
}
```

It's the standard implementation to force landscape mode in a UIViewController. I guess if someone wants to keep there orientation dynamic, they could always get the interfaceOrientation from the rootViewController.